# Setting permalink: none still results in date in URL for Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to set up Jekyll based blog posts on my site, but running into trouble styling the URLs how I'd like (`<site URL>/blog/<blog title>`). Based on the documentation [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), I should be able to do this by either doing `permalink: none` and setting the category to `blog` or by doing `permalink: /:category/:title` or `permalink: /blog/:title` in my `_config.yml` file, but none of these produces the desired result, with even the `none` preset just giving me `/blog/2022/06/22/<blog title>.html`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to introduce a string in the permalink like that.

However, you can try forcing all your posts to have a category `blog` thus allowing you do use `permalink: /:categories/:title`. To do that you can move your posts directory inside a `blog` directory. That'll tell Jekyll that all posts there are part of the `blog` category:

```
$ tree .
├── blog
│   └── _posts
│       └── 2022-06-23-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
[…]
```

A problem with that approach is that other category names will appear in the final URL as well. For example, I created a default Jekyll site (with `jekyll new test`), changed the permalink definition in `_config.yml` and moved the posts directory like above. The resulting permalink for the default post is:

```
http://localhost:4000/blog/jekyll/update/welcome-to-jekyll
```

If you don't care about categories, or if having some posts get extra categories but everything being contained in `/blog`, this should work.